# Will there be another contest when Stack API 2.0 is close to release?

Tags: feature-request, contest, api-v2

Considering Stack API 2.0 will probably focus a lot on administration and write features, I think it would be a good idea to have another contest.

Comment: I think it would be best if we all consider v2.0 to be roughly analogous to Silverlight 5 and Green Lantern in terms of release date.

Comment: Or Perl 6... no wait - v2 of the API will be much sooner than that.

Comment: Or even PHP6 or is that out yet?

Comment: this is now [status-complete] btw.

Answer (score 2):

Its far to early to even speculate as to how v2 of the API will be released, or as to any of the fanfare surrounding it.

Comment: I'm coming around to this way of thinking. v2 will be a distant thing in the future... something for my grandkids to play with :)